# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(mongoose#Document#scope)' of undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose-schema

This the error:

`collection` is a reserved schema pathname and may break some functionality. You are allowed to use it, but use at your own risk. To disable this warning pass `supressReservedKeysWarning` as a schema option.
/Users/sama/Desktop/spbackend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/document/compile.js:174
this.$set.call(this.$__[scopeSymbol] || this, path, v);
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(mongoose#Document#scope)' of undefined
at Model.set [as collection] (/Users/sama/Desktop/spbackend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/document/compile.js:174:32)
at Function.compile (/Users/sama/Desktop/spbackend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4801:30)
at Mongoose._model (/Users/sama/Desktop/spbackend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:551:27)
at Mongoose.model (/Users/sama/Desktop/spbackend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:509:27)
at Object. (/Users/sama/Desktop/spbackend/models/product.js:68:28)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

in product model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    richDescription: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    images: [{
        type: String,
    }],
    brand: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    countInStock: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 255
    },
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    numReviews: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    isFeatured: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    dateCreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    collection: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Collection'
    }
}
)

productSchema.virtual('id').get(function () {
    return this._id.toHexString();
});

productSchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
});

exports.Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

in collection model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const collectionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

collectionSchema.virtual('id').get(function () {
    return this._id.toHexString();
});

collectionSchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
});

exports.Collection = mongoose.model('Collection', collectionSchema);
```

Answer (score 16):

You issue is related to `collection` field in your schema, I had the same issue, it took me time to figure out. See mongo schema reserved fields here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema.reserved

To fix the issue, just rename the field to something else:

```js
collectionName: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Collection'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`collection` is a reserved keyword. You can see the other reserved keywords here:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema.reserved

You'll have to rename the `collection` field to anything else.